# How to implement Material Speed Dial on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, floating-action-button, speed-dial

Is there any native Flutter library for achieving [Material Design Speed Dial](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/#types-of-transitions)?

I found only [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) FAB documentation, but it doesn't say anything about creating a menu out of it, though Material Design FAB documentation says at the top that FAB is supported in Flutter (it doesn't say how much it supports. Only that it supports, which would lead me to understand that it supports everything in the page).

Should I instead develop mine or look for third party libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I'm creating my own Speed Dial. For now, it is part of a very simple project, but once I test it more and add animations, I'll share a final link.

It still don't have animations, because I'm using `Visibility` for showing or hiding the buttons, and it was tested only in `Scaffold`'s FAB, placed on bottom right of screen, so no link for now, sorry. Less than an alpha right now (and I still need to study how one shares an API for adding to dependency).

I hope I'll be able to create a simple and light enough implementation. Easy to use and easy to understand if anybody wishes to take a look into the code later on. I've seen some implementations, but they are very complex and create (in my view) unnecessary extra widgets.

Some implementations I found:

https://flutterawesome.com/flutter-plugin-to-implement-a-material-design-speed-dial/

https://flutterawesome.com/flutter-floating-action-button-with-speed-dial/